# Calling methods from properties in c#

Tags: c#

I am currently learning c# and i am attempting to create a small application that uses SQLite as the database. After much research I was able to figure out how to create a connection, commands, parameters, etc. so everything is working fine.
Part of my code is this:

```
    using var cmd = new SQLiteCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Tasks (TaskName, TaskBody, TaskPriority) Values (@TaskName, @TaskBody, @Taskpriority)";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TaskName", Taskname);
```

I am confused as to why `cmd.Parameters.AddwithValue` works, because to my understanding `cmd.Parameters` is a property of SQLiteCommand  class. `AddwithValue()` is a method of SQLiteParameterCollection class, so how is it that you can call a method from a property? What is that called? and how does it work in the background?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend reading the docs on [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties).

A property is a wrapper of a field (which is a class level variable) that allows control of whether it can be read and written to. A property can be any type, just like how you can create a variable of any type. [Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8) is a property of the class SqlCommand and is of type SqlParameterCollection. Since Parameters has a 'get' applied to it, you are able to get the SqlParameterCollection instance and view its contents and within the SqlParameterCollection class is the method [AddWithValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlParameterCollection_AddWithValue_System_String_System_Object_)

Comment: @KinfOfArrows  so what you are saying is that any time there is a property that is of a type of another class, i can call methods from that class via the property itself instead of having to initialize an instance of that class? is that just in general or SQLite specifically? And is there a name for being able to do that? thank you

Comment: @hescobar yes that's right. To answer the second part, it comes down to the purpose of the class. If you have a class like SqlCommand, its meant to assist with sql commands so it's properties that are there to help you out should be created by that class. If you had a class exists to only hold data so you can transfer the data to somewhere else, the properties may be null since they weren't provided data to transfer. I would recommend finding a tutorial on c# and class basics as that will explain these things.

Comment: @hescobar Initialization of a non-static class inside the property depends on the underlying implementation.  If you are implementing the property that returns a non-static complex type yourself, you should make sure to initialize it before returning it to the client. Otherwise, the client code will throw null reference exception if it tries to access anything from the complex type.